# Uncaught (in promise) Error: This contract object doesn't have address set yet, please set an address first

Tags: web3js, dapps, decentralized-exchange

I'm currently experiencing some trouble with the front end of my code. I've been working on fixing an error for the past three weeks, but unfortunately, I haven't been able to resolve the issue. Specifically, MetaMask isn't popping up when I try to connect my wallet. I'm not sure what's causing this problem, but I suspect it may be due to a mistake in my code. I've checked through my code multiple times, but I need help explaining why MetaMask isn't working correctly. I am stuck in the **"Loading..."** screen. Could you help me fix this error? All the codes and error details are given below. I would really appreciate your assistance if you have any experience with MetaMask or front-end development. Thank you so much!

**JS Console Error:**

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: This contract object doesn't have an address set yet; please set an address first.
    at Object.ContractNoAddressDefinedError (errors.js:122:1)
    at y._processExecuteArguments (index.js:728:1)
    at y._executeMethod (index.js:745:1)
    at getContracts (utils.js:29:1)
    at async init (LoadingContainer.js:13:1)
ContractNoAddressDefinedError @ errors.js:122
y._processExecuteArguments @ index.js:728
y._executeMethod @ index.js:745
getContracts @ utils.js:29
await in getContracts (async)
(anonymous) @ LoadingContainer.js:19
commitHookEffectListMount @ react-dom.development.js:23150
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:24926
commitPassiveMountEffects_complete @ react-dom.development.js:24891
commitPassiveMountEffects_begin @ react-dom.development.js:24878
commitPassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:24866
flushPassiveEffectsImpl @ react-dom.development.js:27039
flushPassiveEffects @ react-dom.development.js:26984
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:26769
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
```

**LoadingContainer.js**

```
import { getWeb3, getContracts } from "./utils.js";
import App from "./App.js";

function LoadingContainer() {
  const [web3, setWeb3] = useState(undefined);
  const [accounts, setAccounts] = useState([]);
  const [contracts, setContracts] = useState(undefined);

  useEffect(() => {
    const init = async () => {
      const web3 = await getWeb3();
      const contracts = await getContracts(web3);
      const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
      setWeb3(web3);
      setContracts(contracts);
      setAccounts(accounts);
    }
    init();
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  const isReady = () => {
    return (
      typeof web3 !== "undefined" 
      && typeof contracts !== "undefined"
      && accounts.length > 0
    );
  }

  if (!isReady()) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <App
      web3={web3}
      accounts={accounts}
      contracts={contracts}
    />
  );
}

export default LoadingContainer;
```

**utils.js**

```
import detectEthereumProvider from '@metamask/detect-provider';
import DecentralizedExchange from './contracts/DecentralizedExchange.json';
import ERC20Abi from './ERC20Abi.json';

const getWeb3 = () =>
  new Promise( async (resolve, reject) => {
    let provider = await detectEthereumProvider();
    if(provider) {
      await provider.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
      try {
        const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
        resolve(web3);
      } catch(error) {
        reject(error);
      }
    }
    reject('Install Metamask');
  });

const getContracts = async web3 => {

  const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
  const deployedNetwork = DecentralizedExchange.networks[networkId];
  const dexcentralizedexchange = new web3.eth.Contract(
    DecentralizedExchange.abi,
    deployedNetwork && deployedNetwork.address,
  );
  const tokens = await dexcentralizedexchange.methods.getTokens().call();
  const tokenContracts = tokens.reduce((acc, token) => ({
    ...acc,
    [web3.utils.hexToUtf8(token.ticker)]: new web3.eth.Contract(
      ERC20Abi,
      token.tokenAddress
    )
  }), {});
  return { dexcentralizedexchange, ...tokenContracts };
}

export { getWeb3, getContracts };
```

**index.js**

````
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./scss/index.scss";
import LoadingContainer from "./LoadingContainer.js";

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<LoadingContainer />)```
````

Comment: can you add the contents of DecentralizedExchange?

Comment: do you men the smart contract?